# Appending 'active' class to bootstrab5

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project in PHP and I couldn't add ClassActive to the bootstrap Navbar

```
    <?php foreach ($category as $cat){echo <li class="nav-item><a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="categories.php?pageid='.$cat['ID'].'">'  .$cat['Name']. '</a></li>';}?>
```

---

Jquery=>

```
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item a').click(function(e) {

    $('.navbar-nav .nav-item a').removeClass('active');

    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    //e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help when no code is included in your question?

Comment: I don't understand your if statement. Why check if the obj have active class, when you remove the active class just above?

Comment: First of all, don't name a variable '$this'. Next a question. when you click a link, you go to another page? in that case your jQuery code works, but you will never see it, because you navigate away from the page you are on.

Comment: @GertB. Well, naming a jQuery variable with a `$` at the beginning is quite often seen on the web. It helps to see which are jQuery objects and not normal DOM elements or javascript variables. Good point about the link visited. But it might be a link with an hashtag to stay on this page and activate a tab or something similar. In any case, Anas's question needs a bit more details on what he wants to do. Depending on that some CSS may do the work without any JS.

Comment: @PatrickJanser variables with a `$` are used in js, and no problem for me. Calling it `$this` is a no go for me. This is a very confusing varname. calling it `var $clickedLink` would be less of a problem for me. The hashtag link is why I asked the question if clicking the link visits another page.

Comment: @GertB. Oh yes! well pointed! I didn't think about the `$this` itself, stupid me! The question has been updated and effectively the link is loading another page, so as you say, no point in adding the `active` class since this could be done with some CSS `.navbar-nav .nav-item a:active`

Comment: The Problem Is Not About Variables Name It's Work With Me In Author Templet But I Think The Problem In Foreach Loop

Comment: The problem is probably that you leave the page, so the js is not executed. the comment about the variable name was a tip.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link in the navigation, the browser will go to that link. To prevent this, you have the line commented out (e.preventDefault). If the application is not a single page application, you can write a function which will be executed on each page load [$(document).on('load, ()=>{});] where you check for the current URL and add the class .active to the corresponding element.

possible solution here [How do I make Bootstrap navbar change active state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530497/how-do-i-make-bootstrap-navbar-change-active-state)

Or like this code from GeeksForGeeks

```
<script>
  
            /* Code for changing active 
            link on clicking */
            var btns = 
                $("#navigation .navbar-nav .nav-link");
  
            for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                btns[i].addEventListener("click",
                                      function () {
                    var current = document
                        .getElementsByClassName("active");
  
                    current[0].className = current[0]
                        .className.replace(" active", "");
  
                    this.className += " active";
                });
            }
  
            /* Code for changing active 
            link on Scrolling */
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var distance = $(window).scrollTop();
                $('.page-section').each(function (i) {
  
                    if ($(this).position().top 
                        <= distance + 250) {
                          
                            $('.navbar-nav a.active')
                                .removeClass('active');
  
                            $('.navbar-nav a').eq(i)
                                .addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }).scroll();
        </script>
```