# How to add and remove class from list items?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have designed a side nav for a website. How can I add a class on click of a nav item and remove it from the previous nav item?

I have tried this solution right here: https://codepen.io/8eni/pen/MaGVrq

I have also tried a bit of jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
<ul class="side_menu" id="sideMenu">
  <li class="list_header">
    <p class="list_p">REVIEWS</p>
    <ul class="sub_list">
      <li class="sub_list_item" style="padding-top: 0px !important;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-layer-group padding_right"></i> All Reviews
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up padding_right"></i> Best Albums
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down padding_right"></i> Worst Albums
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list_header">
    <p class="list_p">GENRES</p>
    <ul class="sub_list">
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i> Dub
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i> Electronica
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
          <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i> Grundge
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want a class to be added to the particular item clicked by a user. Once another item is clicked, the previous item gets the class removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set active class to nav menu from twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082316/how-to-set-active-class-to-nav-menu-from-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure `JavaScript` way to do it (no dependencies). I prevented the default link behaviors for the sake of the demo.

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.sub_list_item');

function setActiveClass() {
  if (document.querySelector('.sub_list_item.active') != null) {
    document.querySelector('.sub_list_item.active').classList.remove('active');  
  } 
  this.classList.add('active');
}

listItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', setActiveClass);
});

// DEMO ONLY — REMOVE
const listLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.sub_list_link');
listLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault());
});
```

```css
.sub_list_item.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="side_menu" id="sideMenu">
  <li class="list_header">
    <p class="list_p">REVIEWS</p>
    <ul class="sub_list">
      <li class="sub_list_item" style="padding-top: 0px !important;">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-layer-group padding_right"></i>
                    All Reviews
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up padding_right"></i>
                    Best Albums
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down padding_right"></i>
                    Worst Albums
                  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list_header">
    <p class="list_p">GENRES</p>
    <ul class="sub_list">
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i>
                    Dub
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i>
                    Electronica
                  </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub_list_item">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" class="sub_list_link">
                    <i class="fas fa-music padding_right"></i>
                    Grundge
                  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tnkL1gaq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sub_list_item').click(function(){
        $('.sub_list_item').removeClass('yourClass');
        $(this).addClass('yourClass');
    });
});
```

Hope this works! The idea is to remove `yourClass` from all nav items and then add it to only the current one.